# Is there an IDictionary implementation that keeps the keys in the order they were added ? (NOT sorted order)

Tags: .net, collections, dictionary

I guess everything is in the title...

I know that `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` does keep the keys in addition order, but only as long as you don't remove any, and anyway this behavior is not documented and can't be relied upon (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154307/why-are-entries-in-addition-order-in-a-net-dictionary) for details).

Basically, what collection should I use if I want an ordered collection of key/value pairs, while keeping an O(1) access time? (`List<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` isn't a good option since it would have O(n) access time). I don't think there is anything like that in the BCL, but I just want to be sure before I roll my own...

Just to make it clear to everyone: I don't want the keys to be *sorted*, I just want them to remain in addition order. So `SortedList`/`SortedDictionary` are not what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you perhaps just keep a `List` and a `Dictionary` that allows you to lookup where keys are in the list? That would allow you to get the key/value pairs in order of addition but still maintain `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: Eventually I used a `LinkedList<T>` rather than a simple `List<T>`, but the idea is the same...

Answer (score 2):

If you can accept non-generic, then [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) may do what you need. Otherwise, I would be tempted to write a wrapper that combines a list and dictionary, using the list for `GetEnumerator` and the dictionary for the indexer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what I'm looking for... too bad it's not generic :(.

Comment: I guess I could write a generic wrapper, but I would lose performance for value types because of boxing, so I guess I will eventually implement my own...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - Generic collections usually don't require boxing.

Comment: @Henk `OrderedDictionary` is non-generic. It depends on what the values are of course; it it maps a string to a class: no boxing.

Comment: Right, I kind of missed it was about the 1st option.

Answer (score 1):

So, you don't want an associative container and the order is completely based on insertion order... why don't you simply use a basic array?

Comment: I'm assuming the lookup may also be by the key, which is not necessarily the same as the int-index.

Comment: As Marc says, I want to lookup items by key; and I don't know beforehand how many items there will be, so an array is not a practical option.

Answer (score 1):

"Addition order" is not normally an issue for a Dictionary, so don't expect one int a std library.

It is of course possible but will always come at the cost of performance. If you find O(1) lookup important I would suggest a wrapper containing a `Dictionary<K,V>` and an coupled `List<K>`. Add and Remove will become slower.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what I'll do

Comment: Actually, Add and Remove don't have to be slower: I used a `LinkedList<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` and a `Dictionary<K, LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<K,V>>>`, so all operations are O(1), unless I'm missing something... (except access by index if it was needed, but it's not)

Comment: O(1), yes. But with different constants.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `SortedDictionary` [with a custom `IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a045f865.aspx) that maintains the insertion order. Whether you want to wrap this in your own more convenient interface is up to you, of course.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how the IComparer would know about the insertion order... Did you have an implementation in mind?

Comment: Since you implement the `IComparer` yourself, and you know the insertion order, you certainly could make one that knows the insertion order. Again, might need some wrapping to be user-friendly.