# sort Dictionary by generic value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have tried to sort a Dictionary object by value which is generic.

Here is my code

```
Dictionary<string, ReportModel> sortedDic = new Dictionary<string, ReportModel>();
Dictionary<string, ReportModel> rDic = new Dictionary<string, ReportModel>();
var ordered = sortedDic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.totalPurchase);
foreach (var item in ordered)
{                           
    rDic.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

The variable, ordered, just has the same order like sortedDic. 
What is wrong with this?
Any idea?

Comment: What type is totalPurchase?

Comment: What's the error do u get ?

Comment: How do you add the items to 'sortedDic'? Does it happen to be from highest to lowest totalPurchase?

Comment: You're setting yourself up for confusion by calling a Dictionary "sortedDic", when, by definition, a Dictionary should be treated as an unsorted set... e.g. there is no implicit sort order. It won't matter what order you insert them into rDic, it will only partially affect the order of rDic, and any such ordering is unspecified and can't be relied upon.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because `Dictionary` is generally an unordered container<sup>*</sup>. When you put the data into `rDic`, it becomes unordered again.

To retain the desired order, you need to put the results into a container that explicitly keeps the ordering that you supply. For example, you could use a list of `KeyValuePair<string,ReportModel>`, like this:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string,ReportModel>> ordered = sortedDic
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.totalPurchase)
    .ToList();
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Due to the way the `Dictionary<K,V>` is implemented by Microsoft, [it happens to retain the insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/976871/335858), but that is incidental and undocumented, so it may change in the future versions, and should not be relied upon.

Comment: I tested the above code and it worked in my scenario. Was i just lucky?

Comment: @LuisFilipe That's no luck, it's an undocumented implementation detail that I mentioned in the footnote to the answer ([click this link for more info of what is going on there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/976871/335858)).

Comment: @user1713153 You are welcome! If you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, you may want to accept the answer to indicate that it has worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the items back to the dictionary, it would not keep their order.
You can either:

1. Use the [following implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18615/OrderedDictionary-T-A-generic-implementation-of-IO).
2. Use a list in the below form.

   ```
   IEnumrable> lst=
      sortedDic.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.totalPurchase).ToArray();
   ```
3. [EDIT] If you don't mind the key changing then you can use SortedDictionary<,>.

Comment: .Net Framework already provides the 'SortedDictionary<,>' data type for such a thing.

Comment: Yea, I don't think he wants the key to change but this is correct. I will add that.